# getting invalid parameter error while using prometheus api from postman

Tags: prometheus, promql

I encountered this error while trying to run the memory usage query but seems like whenever the query encounters '+' operator, the below error is thrown. There is no error while using other operators like '-', '/' and '*'.
The issue is seen in Postman and also when I try to run the query using Python requests lib. The query works well in Grafana and Prometheus Web UI.

Get - http:///api/v1/query?query=count(up{instance=~".*:9100"} == 1) + 100
Query - count(up{instance=~".*:9100"} == 1) + 100
Error -
{
"status": "error",
"errorType": "bad_data",
"error": "invalid parameter "query": 1:39: parse error: unexpected number "100""
}

Prometheus Version - 2.48.1

Comment: `+` has a special meaning in URLs: it's used as a replacement for spaces. More generally, you should urlencode your queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must URL encode query string parameters both the key (`query`) and the value (in this case your PromQL) i.e. `count(up{instance=~".:9100"} == 1) + 100`.

Using [URLencoder](https://www.urlencoder.org/), yields:

`count%28up%7Binstance%3D~%22.%3A9100%22%7D%20%3D%3D%201%29%20%2B%20100`

`query` is unchanged, thus:

`api/v1/query?query=count%28up%7Binstance%3D~%22.%3A9100%22%7D%20%3D%3D%201%29%20%2B%20100`